Cannot debug NestJS application at all with VSCode - 0 configuration
I've seen some related threads regarding this issue, but none of the solutions helped me.
I set up simple NestJS application, nothing special, but I fail to use VSCode debugger.
It's important to note that I use package dotenv-cli together, which leads to this script in my package.json:
"start:debug": "dotenv -e ./.env.development -e ../../prisma/.env.development -- nest start --debug --watch"

I'm not sure whether it interrupts the debugger or not.
Anyway, I tried this script, while running the "JavaScript Debug Terminal" and no debug occurs.
Then, I saw that some people suggests this .vscode/launch.json file:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Nest Framework",
            "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts"],
            "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register", "-r", "tsconfig-paths/register"],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
    ]
}

And then I tried again and it didn't help, so I'm not sure what's happening here.
I also tried the command >Debug: Toggle Auto Attach
